# Accessing calendars in Mac Objective-C program

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, eventkit

This bit of code is intended to print my default calendar in iCal on my Mac but instead returns (null). Do I need to change something in the code or settings to be able to access my calendars? I'm running this in Xcode 4.5.2.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <EventKit/EventKit.h>


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] initWithAccessToEntityTypes:EKEntityMaskEvent];
    NSLog(@"%@",[store defaultCalendarForNewEvents].calendarIdentifier);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Related: [Problems accessing Calendar using EKEventStore on OSX Sierra with Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40298000/4975230)

Answer (score 1):

For me the above code returns the identifier of the default calendar correctly (on 10.8.2).

Is your application sandboxed? The result will be `(null)` if you don't allow calendar access while sandboxed:

[image]

I'm not sure if this is possible at all, but also check if there is a default calendar selected. (I have one selected, and could not set the selection to none in Calendar.app).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'm on 10.7.5 and I think that this might be the problem but I'm not sure where you found the checkbox to allow Calendar Data Access. Is this a setting in Xcode somewhere?

Comment: Yes, its the `com.apple.security.personal-information.calendars` setting in your sandbox entitlements file. You can configure sandboxing by going to the Summary tab of your target configuration. The [App Sandbox Design Guide: Quick start](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxQuickStart/AppSandboxQuickStart.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH2-SW3) might be of help.

Comment: I found the options for sandboxing when I created a new Cocoa Application (I had been choosing Command Line Tool). I made sure that sandbox mode was unchecked but still no luck. I don't think code signing should be required to access the calendar data, right? I get no errors in Xcode but I did find an interesting message in Console: 1/23/13 12:33:50.309 AM getEvents: (null)
1/23/13 12:33:50.312 AM com.apple.debugserver-194: 2 +0.172950 sec [11f5/1a03]: error: ::read ( 1, 0x10a3c9a60, 1024 ) => -1 err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009)

Comment: For me it only seemed to work when sandboxed. I didn't find any documentation about `EKEventStore` and sandboxing, so I'm not sure if this behaviour is intended or a bug.