# Problems accessing Calendar using EKEventStore on OSX Sierra with Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, ekeventstore

This appears very simple, but I've been struggling for several days to get access to the Calendar on OSX.  I have switched on the App Sandbox capability, and I've ticked the "Calendar" box in App Data.  I have created very simple app with the following view controller class:

```
import Cocoa
import EventKit

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    var eventControl = EKEventStore()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the only lines of code I've added are to import EventKit and to initialise eventControl.

When I run this in debug, I get an error at the eventControl initialisation line

```
2016-10-28 15:02:00.056521 calendarTest[4105:847101] CoreData: XPC:     Unable to load metadata: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134070 "An error occurred in the persistent store." UserInfo={Problem=request failed, insufficient permission}
2016-10-28 15:02:00.057742 calendarTest[4105:847101] [error] error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:NSXPCStore configuration:(null) URL:file:///Users/patrickramsden/Library/Calendars/Calendar%20Cache  options:{
    NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption = 1;
    NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption = 1;
    agentOrDaemon = 1;
    serviceName = "com.apple.CalendarAgent.database";
} ... returned error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134070 "An error occurred in the persistent store." UserInfo={Problem=request failed, insufficient permission} with userInfo dictionary {
    Problem = "request failed, insufficient permission";
}
```

I can't work out how to get the right permissions.

I am using Xcode 8.1 and macOS Sierra 10.12.1

Comment: After lots of further testing, it seems that although this error is reported, the code still executes correctly.  `eventControl` is being set to a valid object, and I am able to execute EventKit operations on that object successfully.  I believe this error does not cause any problems.

Comment: For me the error is not a false positive, it just never runs the callback (not at all), I would have expected it to run the callback with an error, but that doesn't seem to happen. I think there might be just something broken with permissions requests for terminal programs. One of the weirder things I noticed, only when I ran the program outside of XCode's debugger (i.e., when I ran it from the terminal) macOS asked me for contacts permissions (???) even though I was requesting reminder permissions? Even after I granted it, it seemed to have no effect at all, same error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add a usage description to your info.plist. This is a small description of why you need access to the services that is presented to the user.

```
<key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
<string>Description of why you need access to the Calendar</string>
```

Comment: I think this is for ios, and it does not work for me anyway. I had an app working perfectly on Sierra and since i updated to Mojave i get this error. The thing is i do not even call the code, but when i do i get that the authorization is not determined, although in privacy i have granted xcode.

Comment: same issue as @CristiBăluță

Comment: Btw, i am confused a little, i knew that when apps are run from xcode  the request for granting access comes from xcode, but after a while and some relaunches it started to work and the access is granted for the app.

Comment: If you have HardenedRuntime and AppSandbox - calendar needs to be checked there too.

Comment: This didn't seem to have any effect for me.

Answer (score 2):

Has anyone else figured this out?
I am running into the same issue, however trying to access anything in the event Store returns nil. Even though "access is granted". Such as:

```
let eventStore = EKEventStore()
switch EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: .event) {
  case .authorized:
    print("Access Granted")
    break
  case .denied:
    print("Access denied")
  case .notDetermined:
    eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event, completion:
      {(granted: Bool, error: Error?) -> Void in
        if granted {
          print("Access Granted")

        } else {
          print("Access denied")
        }
    })
    break
  default:
    print("Case Default")
  break
}

print(eventStore.calendars(for: .event))
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the same messages: [How to prevent EventStore access error on first run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60851829/how-to-prevent-eventstore-access-error-on-first-run)

However the access is working correctly once you start the application again after the user grants permission! My app is not sandboxed. Have you set the "Privacy - Calendars Usage Description" key in your plist?